# how to add a single record in to table which has foreign key using EF code first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have two tables

```
ToDo
   ToDoId [PK],
   Title,
   description,
   Category ,
   AssignedDate ,
   DueDate
```

```
TaskReview 
    ReviewId, 
    Rating ,
    Comment, 
    ToDoId [FK]
```

-i have to add rating and comment to task review table using the foreign key ToDoId
-Basically add a rating and comment to a particular task using TodiId.

```
 public int AddRatingAndComment(int ToDoId, int rating,string comment)
        {
            
            using (var ctx = new Context())
            {
                //add rating and comment in task review table 

            }
           

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the ToDo table has a list of TaskReview items ([one-to-many realtion](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)) then you can fetch existing ToDo and add a new TaskReview item.

```
ToDo todo = ctx.ToDos.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ToDoId == ToDoId);
if(todo != null)
{
    todo.TaskReviews.Add(new TaskReview(){...});
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

If there is a one-to-one relation between ToDo and TaskReview you would declare a variable of type ToDo in the TaskReview model. ([One-to-One relation](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx))
Now if you want to add TaskReview to the existing Todo, You can fetch it and use it to add a new TaskReview:

```
ToDo todo = ctx.ToDos.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ToDoId == ToDoId);
if(todo != null)
{
    var addedTaskReview = new TaskReview(){
       ToDo = todo,
       ...
    };
    ctx.TaskReview.Add(addedTaskReview);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

> One-To-One implementation

```
    public class ToDo
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ToDoId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public DateTime AssignedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
        public virtual TaskReview TaskReview { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class TaskReview
    {
        [ForeignKey("ToDo")]
        public int TaskReviewId { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public virtual ToDo ToDo { get; set; }
    }
    
    using (var ctx = new SchoolContext())
    {
          var toDo = ctx.Todos.Where(o => o.ToDoId == todoId).FirstOrDefault();
    
          var taskReview = new TaskReview
          {
               ToDo = toDo,
               Comment = "accepted",
               Rating = 10
          };
           ctx.TaskReviews.Add(taskReview);
           ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: i tired this code but got the following error  'The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.TaskReviews_dbo.ToDoes_ToDoId '

Comment: Check the One-To-One implementation part in my previous answer. I just added it. It worked fine for me. If you need a One-To-Many implementation sample, let me know.